# Schengen visa to spain

Tags: schengen, spain, change-purpose-of-travel

I have got Schengen visa -spain and due to travel June first week . This is a single entry business visa and I am traveling to Madrid for business meetings.After the visa is secured I was thinking of flying to Paris from Madrid and spend two days there before returning from Paris CDG to Muscat Oman ( visa issued by Spanish embassy muscat )Does it cause any problem traveling to Paris with as I have not mentioned in visa application to spain embassy of my travel plan to Paris? I am concerned if there could be trouble in Madrid airport immigration on arrival as my return ticket is from Paris not from Madrid as visa application was for business not tourist purpose.Visa valid for Estados Schengen , visa type : C single entry , duration of stay :15 days , remarks : VIS Estancia. Under remarks it is written indomeest.I have travelled to spain and Germany earlier but have not changed my travel plans after getting visa to travel to another Schengen state.
Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a Schengen visa is issued, it is valid for travel anywhere in the Schengen area in the period of its validity.

There are some caveats about the possibility of the visa being canceled if the reasons for issuing it are not true anymore (or never were) -- but that **doesn't apply to you**, since you're actually going for the the business purpose you described in your visa application. So it is completely fine to tack a bit of tourism on to your business trip, as long as you have time for everything within the 15 days of validity.

The border guards do not have access to the details of your application anyway, so the only thing that could make them suspicious is if you come prepared for a trip where *you should not have applied to Spain in the first place*. But the *actual* trip you're describing (business in Spain, followed by tourism in France) is **still** one that Spain should be processing, so it cannot even be seen from your visa that it wasn't the trip you described in the application. (Though again, even if the border guards knew you have amended your plans, you're still not doing anything wrong -- but they don't).

Comment: As the OP describes it, the *original premise* is still valid and he is making *minor adjustments* to the route to and from the main event. That's what Schengen is supposed to simplify! Enjoy Paris.

Comment: @o.m.: I hope I didn't say anything to conflict with that.